# print(",".join(result)+"\n") how to get same result but with writing to a file

Tags: python, file

I wanted to remove the square brackets from my print statement, and its working fine with print but i cant get it to work with write to file.

this is my print statement which is working perfectly:

```
 print(",".join(result)+"\n")
```

i have tried this code to write to the file but it still shows the square brackets.

```
 output.write("".join(str(result)+"\n"))
```

my ideal result which are showing with the print statement is this:

```
text1.1,text1.2

text2

text3.1,text3.2
```

but my write statement is giving me this:

```
['text1.1', 'text1.2']
['text2']
['text3.1', 'text3.2']
[]
```

Comment: `output.write(",".join(result)+"\n")`?

Comment: What is the type of `result`?

Comment: [learn about ' '.join()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html)

Comment: You can use the `file` parameter of `print` to write to a file: `print(",".join(result)+"\n", file=output)`. If `result` contains non-string data you could try `print(*result, sep=',', file=output)`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

when using `join()` you provide a iterable having elements whose type is `str` .
so for each element it join it to a result string which are seperated by character  `' '` mentioned `' '.join()`

so see the result of the approach you are using below

```
result =['0', '1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9']
# when using the right way
line = ','.join(result)

# what you are doing

line2 = ','.join(str(result))

print(line, line2,sep = '\n')

# line -> 0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9
# line2 -> [,',0,',,, ,',1,',,, ,',2,',,, ,',3,',,, ,',4,',,, ,',5,',,, ,',6,',,, ,',7,',,, ,',8,',,, ,',9,',]
```

so you don't need to convert the list of string i.e. `result` to string ie `str(result)`
just pass the `result` to `join`.